# List of text in one Card using ListView.builder twice and for loop?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

With my current code, my list is put into separate cards. I need it to be in one. I'm using two `ListView.builder`s and a loop. I believe that's what's causing the problem. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Every time the user taps submit on my second `TextField` a new `TextField` appears, functionality I would like to keep one way or another.

I'm just staring out so any help if appreciated.

[image: example]

My end goal is to have a bullet point list but the bullet points aren't important right now.

Here's my code:

```
class PostNote extends StatefulWidget {
      User user;
  PostNote({
    required this.user,
  });

  @override
  State<PostNote> createState() => _PostNoteState();
}

class _PostNoteState extends State<PostNote> {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();

  final List<TextField> _textFields = [];
  final List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [];

  bool loading = false;

    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _addTextField();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF162242),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              children: [

                Text(
                "Title",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),

                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),

                Container(
                height: 60,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                    ),
                  ),
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF192A4F),
                    fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                  controller: titleController,
                  autofocus: true,
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),

                Text(
                "Notes",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),

              Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(10),
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: ListView.builder( // HERE
              shrinkWrap: true,
             itemCount: _textFields.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return _textFields[index];
                },
            ),
          ),

SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              loading
                  ? Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )
                  : Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          child: Text(
                            "Add Note",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Color(0xFF162242)),
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            for (var notesController in _controllers) // HERE {
                              if (titleController.text == "" ||
                                  notesController.text.isEmpty) {
                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                    SnackBar(
                                        content:
                                            Text("All fields are required")));
                              } else {
                                setState(() {
                                  loading = true;
                                });

                                await FirestoreServiceEdit().insertNote(
                                    titleController.text,
                                    notesController.text,
                                    widget.user.uid);

                                    CollectionReference notes =
                                firestore.collection('notes');
                            QuerySnapshot allResults = await notes.get();
                            allResults.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot result) {
                              print(result.data());
                            });

                            if (!mounted) return;

                            setState(() {
                              loading = false;
                            });

                            Navigator.pop(context);
                              }
                            }
                          }),
                    ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _addTextField() {
    final notesController = TextEditingController();
    _textFields.add(
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefix: Icon(
            Icons.circle,
            size: 8,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        autofocus: true,
        controller: notesController,
        onSubmitted: (_) => setState(() => _addTextField()), 
      ),
    );
    _controllers.add(notesController);
  }
}
```

```
class FirestoreServiceEdit{

  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future insertNote(String title, String notes, String? userId,)async{
    try{
      await firestore.collection('notes').add({
        "title":title,
        "notes":notes,
        "userId":userId
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  }
}
```

```
class NoteModelEdit {
  String id;
  String title;
  String notes;
  String userId;

  NoteModelEdit({
    required this.id,
     required this.title,
    required this.notes,
    required this.userId
  });

  factory NoteModelEdit.fromJson(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    return NoteModelEdit(
      id: snapshot.id,
      title: snapshot['title'],
      notes: snapshot['notes'],
      userId: snapshot['userId']
      );  
  }
}
```

Home screen:

```
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("notes")
              .where('userId', isEqualTo: user.uid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (snapshot.data.docs.length > 0) {
                return ListView.builder( // HERE
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      NoteModelEdit note =
                          NoteModelEdit.fromJson(snapshot.data.docs[index]);
                      return Card(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 18, left: 15, right: 15),
                        child: Column(children: [
                          ListTile(
                            title: Center(
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border(
                                    bottom: BorderSide(width: 0.5),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                  note.title,
                                  textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.longestLine,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 40,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => EditNoteScreen(),
                              ));
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              note.notes,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                        ]),
                      );
                    });
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: If possible, it may be easier to change your storage model to be a list of strings for the notes. This way you can apply the desired visual elements (eg. bullets) in front of each chunk and not need to guess with something like a line break.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and look into that more. For now, can you tell me how to have the list in one card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to augment your logic to look at all the TextFields at the same time rather than one at a time and inserting a note for each.

```
if (titleController.text.isEmpty ||
  _controllers.any((element) => element.text.isEmpty)) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
        content:
            Text("All fields are required")));
} else {
  setState(() {
    loading = true;
  });
}

await FirestoreServiceEdit().insertNote(
  titleController.text,
  _controllers.map((element) => element.text).join("\n"),
  widget.user.uid);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this :

```
 Widget listInCard() {
    List testList = ["note1", "note2", "note3"];
    return Card(
      color: Colors.blue.shade200,
      elevation: 5,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: testList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text(testList[index]);
          }),
    );
  }
```

[image]

The blue color is the Card and inside it, it is a list of notes.
You can also use Container instead of Card.